# Swipe Support in Angular JS

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working on AngularJs application and i wanted to tab content with swipe support.
iam new to angular and i don't have much idea on angular facilities. below is my code

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="Tab Item 1">
        <h3 class="header">Heading 1</h3>
        <div class="body">
        Body Conten one
        </div>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Tab Item 3">
        <h3 class="header">Heading 2</h3>
        <div class="body">
        Body Conten Two
        </div>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Tab Item 3">
        <h3 class="header">Heading 3</h3>
        <div class="body">
        Body Conten Three
        </div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

When user swipe on tab content it should be support swipe. please help me to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

there are directives ng-swipe-left="fn1()" and ng-swipe-right="fn2()".

fn1 is called when your are swipe left of the screen and  fn2 called when swipe right of the screen.
Better to use this in top div.

```
<div ng-swipe-left="fn1()" ng-swipe-right="fn2()></div>
```

You have make sure to use `$event.stopPropagation();` in all ng-click or any other events inside this div
so,

```
<div ng-swipe-left="fn1()" ng-swipe-right="fn2()>

<div ng-click="fun3();$event.stopPropagation();"></div>

 </div>
```

so here use this in each tab and implement hiding and showing using ng-hide or ng-show. Also use some opacity and transition in css in order to move from left to right and vice versa.

Comment: could you please add a example  please? plunker also fine.  my requirement is when user swipe next item should show  if user swipe to right side previous item should show

Answer (score 0):

You could use ngTouch module as suggested or you could write your own Angular directive using HTML5 multi-touch events. I did just that to enable simple navigation much like the one OP presented. Directive is bound to the element which we want to swipe via an attribute and can be used like this:

```
<tab heading="Tab Item 2" my-swipe="[goLeft, goRight]">
```

where goLeft and goRight are functions on the controller that contains the swipable element - see this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/43Z3bk?p=preview) for complete code and example of use.

Directive starts moving the content as soon as swipe gesture is detected and executes the function on touchEnd event, so it feels quite natural.